# input form to sql with default value

Tags: php, sql, forms

i have form with 2 value

```
fullname : [______________]
job : [______________]
```

but i need to put on my sql with structure

```
+---------+-----------+-------------+
| fullname| job       | status      |
+---------+-----------+-------------+
```

with default status value "1"

what is the script under php

so far i use this script

```
if(isset($_GET['prosesdata']))
   {
    $query = "Insert INTO am (name, job, status) values('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[job]','$_POST[status]')";
    //echo $query; exit;
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if(!$result)
```

like i said before, it only enter 2 value from name and job , i have no idea how to put the status

Comment: you want us to write a code...how to insert the record ?

Comment: have you tried anything so far..??

Comment: updated post , i use that query at my php file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Do not merge `GET` and `POST`
- Do not use `mysql_*` which is deprecated.
- Use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.

use post as form method.

In php,

```
$fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
$job = $_POST['job'];
$status = 1;

$sql = "INSERT INTO your_table_name (fullname,job,status) values ($fullname,$job,$status)";
```

Comment: it's work , and i got the point... set the var then use insert into <br> thank you so much,<br><hr> but i dont understand what you mean about dont merge get and post and dont use mysql_* sorry im new @Niranjan

Comment: either use `GET` or `POST`, in your code you have used both which is not preferred.

Comment: `mysql_` which you have used in your code is officially deprecated, so use `mysql_*`, or `PDO`. Which i can say the advanced version of `mysql_` with lot of added advantage.

Comment: verywell, i will try to get some information from google<br> thank you for your information, maybe from now i will use google search tool with relevant time

Comment: Do that, thats how u ll improve. Good luck.

Comment: oot : i got blocked can not post new question, how to unblock it ?

Comment: you deleted some questions of yours??

Comment: nope.....<br> today i want to write some question, but i cant post. after i read on top, it say something with my previous post, but i cant find which one that having problem. i check my log, perhaps minus (-) flag, but i can not fix it ...